# jQuery .prev() not working well

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am coding a front-end of shopping website and the scenario is: 
If we have an sale offer then first the previous price must line-through and beside the price € inserted.

So this is my jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('.price span.price-new').text().length !=  '') {
    this.prev('.price span.price-new').before("€").text(); 
    this.prev("span").css({"text-decoration": "line-through"});

}
      });
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<?php                                           
    foreach( $this->products() as $products)
        {
echo
'<div class="price"><span class="price-old">€&nbsp;'.$products['price'].'</span>'.
'<span class="price-new">'.$products['special_price'].'</span></div>'.'</div>';}?>
```

Both of them didn't work.
I tried with $(this) it didn't work too and because of we have many price-new class I can't mentioned the specific class for edit, I use prevUntil too but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be more like this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.price-old').css({"text-decoration": "line-through"});
    $('.price-new').text(function(index, old_text) {
        return "€" + old_text;
    })
});
```

(What is all the extra code for?)

Comment: No, because we .price-old and .price-new repeated in columns and with your code all .price-old classes get that style and all price-new get price symbol, and extra code is for first confirm we have a new price then insert and edit css.

Answer (score 0):

well you'r code is doesn't follow the jquery rules.

```
.text().length !=  ''
```

`.length` this option always return integer value so you can't compair like this `!=  ''`

here

```
this.prev('.price span.price-new').before("€").text(); 
this.prev("span").css({"text-decoration": "line-through"});
```

acording to your code `.prev` mean `$(document).prev`

try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.price span.price-new').each(function() {

     $(this).prev().before("€"); 
     }
});
```

If you can give me little bit more explanation, I can give you a better one

Comment: Thank you, look I have some spans called price-new and price-old and they repeated frequently in price class as it is an ecommerce shop so I want first if we have a a new price or not (like what I coded it was not equal empty span) then put a € sign in before mentioned span and then old class of that span line-through because we have an offer price!

Comment: Nope, Stillhave problem

Answer (score 0):

`this` work with respect to scope and in document scope this refer to window object that is why it is not working. you have to select particular element and then try prev().

Comment: I have some repeated class like price-old and price-new so how I can mention specific class which frequently repeated, another word how I can mention current div or span which I want to operate something in it